# Gradle: How to remove static tasks of NativeLibrarySpec

Tags: gradle, java-native-interface

My gradle 2.3 build script for a jni library looks like this. Is there a possibility to remove the tasks that are created for building a static lib? Or even better a way to prevent the static tasks from being created?

```
model {
    toolChains {
        clang(Clang)
    }
    buildTypes {
        release
    }
    components {
        myNativeLib(NativeLibrarySpec) {
            binaries.all {
                if (toolChain in Clang && buildType == buildTypes.release) {
                    cppCompiler.args '-O3', '-mavx2',
                        "-I${javaHome}/../include",
                        "-I${javaHome}/../include/darwin", // os-dependent
                        "-I${buildDir}/javah" // output of javah
                    linker.args "-o${buildDir}/binaries/${nativeLibrary}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all static tasks like this:

```
model {
    toolChains {
        clang(Clang)
    }
    buildTypes {
        release
    }
    components {
        myNativeLib(NativeLibrarySpec) {
            binaries.all {
                if (toolChain in Clang && buildType == buildTypes.release) {
                    cppCompiler.args '-O3', '-mavx2',
                        "-I${javaHome}/../include",
                        "-I${javaHome}/../include/darwin", // os-dependent
                        "-I${buildDir}/javah" // output of javah
                    linker.args "-o${buildDir}/binaries/${nativeLibrary}"
                }
            }
            // removes all static tasks
            binaries.withType(StaticLibraryBinarySpec) {
                binaries.remove(it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With gradle 2.8 I get: No signature of method: org.gradle.model.ModelMap.remove() is applicable for argument types: (org.gradle.nativeplatform.internal.DefaultStaticLibraryBinarySpec_Decorated)